# Adding new user information from Firebase v8 to v9

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a code to create user with image and username to Firebase v8 and I can't replace it to Firebase v9.

Can someone help me? Thank you!

```
    import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
    import { projectAuth, projectStorage, projectFirestore } from '../firebase/config'
    import { useAuthContext } from './useAuthContext'
    
    export const useSignup = () => {
      const [isCancelled, setIsCancelled] = useState(false)
      const [error, setError] = useState(null)
      const [isPending, setIsPending] = useState(f`enter code here`alse)
      const { dispatch } = useAuthContext()
    
    
          // upload user thumbnail
          const uploadPath = `thumbnails/${res.user.uid}/${thumbnail.name}`
          const img = await projectStorage.ref(uploadPath).put(thumbnail)
          const imgUrl = await img.ref.getDownloadURL()
    
          // add display AND PHOTO_URL name to user
          await res.user.updateProfile({ displayName, photoURL: imgUrl })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import {st, db} from '../firebase/config'
import { getDownloadURL, ref, uploadBytesResumable } from 'firebase/storage';
import { doc, setDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';

const _storageRef = ref(st, "thumbnails/" + res.user.uid + "/" + thumbnail.name)
const _uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(_storageRef, file);

_uploadTask.on("state_changed", (snapshot) => {
    console.log((snapshot.bytesTransferred/snapshot.totalBytes) * 100)
},(error) => {
    console.error(error)
}, async () => {
    await getDownloadURL(_storageRef)
          .then((url) => {
               //update database with the new image url
               console.log(url)
               //setDoc(doc(db, "users", uid), {
               //      photoURL: url
               //   }, {merge: true}) <- to not erase the rest of the values like displayName
          })
           .catch(error => console.error(error))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files) has examples of both <kbd>V8 (namespaced)</kbd> and <kbd>V9 (Modular)</kbd> syntax. You can just switch to modular tab for reference. For this case, try refactoring the code as shown below:

```
import { ref, uploadBytes } from "firebase/storage"
import { updateProfile } from "firebase/auth"

const storageRef = ref(projectStorage, `thumbnails/${res.user.uid}/${thumbnail.name}`);

// 'file' comes from the Blob or File API
// uploadBytes() instead of .put()
uploadBytes(storageRef, file).then(async (snapshot) => {
  console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');

  // updateProfile() is now a top-level function
  // and not a method on User object
  await updateProfile(res.user, {
    displayName: name
  });
  console.log("User profile updated")
});
```

Also do ensure that you've initialized auth and storage using `getAuth()` and `getStorage()` respectively.

Checkout:

- [Upload files with Cloud Storage on Web](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_from_a_blob_or_file)
- [Update user profile using Firebase Modular SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70830141/13130697)